# php - Meaning of question mark colon operator

Tags: php, operator-keyword

What does `?:` in this line mean?

```
$_COOKIE['user'] ?: getusername($_COOKIE['user']);
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: ?: means ternary operator

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is a shorthand for an `if` statement.

```php
$username = $_COOKIE['user'] ?: getusername($_COOKIE['user']);
```

Is the same as

```php
if( $_COOKIE['user'] ) 
{
    $username = $_COOKIE['user'];
} 
else
{
    $username = getusername($_COOKIE['user']); 
}
```

see test suite here: https://3v4l.org/6XMc4

But in this example, the function 'getusername' probably doesn't work correct, because it hits the `else` only when `$_COOKIE['user']` is `empty`. So, the parameter inside `getusername()` is also kind of empty.

Comment: if this line is `$username = $_COOKIE['user'] ?: getusername($_COOKIE['user']);`. Does that mean `if($_COOKIE['user']) {
    $username = $_COOKIE['user'];
} else {
    $username = getusername($_COOKIE['user']);
}`?

Comment: I got it now. Thank you.

Comment: Note with the ternary operator that your variable is going to be set to the output of your conditional. So while `$a = $b ?: $c;` will set `$a` to equal either `$b` or `$c` in all cases, `$a = ($b > 5) ?: $c;` then `$a` will only ever equal `true` or `$c` and never `$b`. It's a tricky nuance.

Comment: Aw, I thought I could use it like `$var = isset($something) ?: $something` and I'd get `if (isset($result)) { $var = $result } else { $var = false; }`. Back to using `$var = isset($something) ? $something : null` for me... :<

Comment: FYI if you want to test if a variable, array key, object parameter, etc. exists (same as `isset()` or `empty()`) and if not assign another value you can use the `??` operator instead. For example: `$myVar = $varNotExists ?? 'this will be the value of $myVar because $varNotExists does not exist';`

Answer (score 2):

It is short hand php, for example:

`(true == true ? echo "this is true" : "this is false")`

Written out this means:

```
if (true == true) {
    echo "This is true";
}
else {
    echo "This is false";
}
```

In your example, there is only an else statement.

Answer (score 1):

It's known as the ternary operator, similar to what's commonly called an inline if.  For instance, the following two examples:

a) `$genderString = $genderAbbreviation == "M" ? "Male" : "Female";`

b)

```
if ($genderAbbreviation == "M")
{
    $genderString = "Male";
}
else
{
    $genderString = "Female";
}
```

Both of these will have the same effect.  The statement before the question mark is evaluated to be either true or false, and then if true the statement before the colon is executed, and if false the statement after the colon is executed.

For more information you can check the section titled "Ternary Operator" on the following page of the PHP documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

if `$_COOKIE['user']` value is exist then `NULL` else `getusername($_COOKIE['user']` will work

it's a **ternary operator** in php

Comment: ***ternary*** operator.